# Get certain parts out of a string using C

Tags: string, search

Evening everyone hope on of you gurus can help. I am trying to find the answer to this issue I need to read the data out of the string below by searching the tags. i.e IZTAG UKPART etc however the code I am using is no good as it only stores the 1st part of it for example UKPART = 12999 and misses out the -0112. Is there a better way to search strings ?

UPDATE SO FAR.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <windows.h>  

int main ()  
{  
    // in my application this comes from the handle and readfile 
    char buffer[255]="TEST999.UKPART=12999-0112...ISUE-125" ;     
    // 
    int i;  
    int codes[256];   
    char *pos = buffer;   
    size_t current = 0;   
    //   
       char buffer2[255];
   if ((pos=strstr(pos, "UKPART")) != NULL) {   
        strcpy (buffer2, pos); // buffer2 <= "UKPART=12999-0112...ISUE-125"
   }

        printf("%s\n", buffer2);  
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;  
}
```

NOW WORKS BUT RETURN WHOLE STRING AS OUTPUT I NEED TO JUST RETURN UKPART FOR EXAMPLE THANKS SO FAR :-)

Comment: While it is not completely defined what you want, splitting with a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) is more flexible.

Comment: @tiwo: excellent suggestion.  Here's another link: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense without the code, so I've reverted your removal of it.

Answer (score 2):

1. strstr() is absolutely the right way to search for the substring.  Cool :)
2. It sounds like you want something different from "sscanf()" to copy the substring.

Q: Why not just use "strcpy ()" instead?

```
EXAMPLE:
   char buffer[255]="IZTAG-12345...UKPART=12999-0112...ISUE-125" ;     
   char buffer2[255];
   if ((pos=strstr(pos, "UKPART")) != NULL) {   
        strcpy (buffer2, pos); // buffer2 <= "UKPART=12999-0112...ISUE-125"
```

Comment: I have never used this feature before sorry I have just moved from php. You mean just replace sscanf with strcpy? sorry for the stupid question.

Comment: Q: Exactly what "doesn't work"?  Please post an error message, if possible.  Q: Did you remember to declare "buffer2" before you used it?  Is "codes" a better variable to read the data into?  MOST IMPORTANT: Q: Is "UKPART=12999-0112...ISUE-125" the result you want to read?

Comment: Sorry I didnt make it clear I just need the UKPART=12999-0112 only to be returned and not the end of the string. As this is another tag. Output now UKPART=12999-0112...ISUE-125 needs to be UKPART=12999-0112 Thanks so far paul.